# Image tag style.height not overriding css class height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

Css

```
.myStyle {
height: 10px;
background-image: url(../myImage.png);
}
```

html

```
<img class=myStyle src=<%scriptlet%> >
```

Now the problem is in my js, i have written a error handler for this img tag, which would set the height to 0px. This 0px comes as style.height=0px but does not override height of class myStyle.

js

```
myImage = $('.myStyle', $el);
myImage.error(function () {
           myImage.attr('style.height', '0px');
});
```

Comment: You should read this http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/jquery-basics

Comment: I have posted my second qusetion on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230762/read-the-background-image-attribute-value-of-the-mystyle-in-error-handler-and

Comment: Thanks everyone for prompt response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change:

```
myImage.attr('style.height', '0px');
```

to

```
myImage.css('height', '0');
```

To get background image, you can use getting, like

```
myImage.css("background");
```

OR

```
myImage.css("backgroundImage")
```

Comment: thanks. this works. Do u know the solution for my second question also? myImage.attr('src', background-image);?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```js
myImage.height(0);
```

Instead of:

```js
myImage.attr('style.height', '0px');
```

The `attr()` is made for attribute manipulation, so in order for the later declaration to work, you may also change it to:

```js
myImage.attr('style', 'height: 0px;');
```

See [`attr()` on the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
myImage.height('10px');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myImage.style.height = '0px';
```

This will also work.