# read the 'background-image' attribute value of the .myStyle in error handler and set it to src?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

Css

```
.myStyle {
height: 10px;
background-image: url(../myImage.png);
}
```

html

```
<img class=myStyle src=<%scriptlet%> >
```

is there a way i can read the 'background-image' attribute value of the .myStyle in error handler and set it to src ?

Following code is not working:
js

```
myImage = $('.myStyle', $el);
myImage.error(function () {
          myImage.attr('src', background-image);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
// change src from element by a css background image from same element.
function changeSrcByCssBackground() {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).css("background-image").slice(4, -1));
}

// do when error
myImage.error(changeSrcByCssBackground);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the `background-image` value, do this:

```
var bgImage = myImage.css("background-image");
```

Take note that the value of `bgImage` will be `url(../myImage.png)`.

So you need to do this:

```
myImage.attr('src', bgImage.slice(4,-1));
```

Comment: lol after that I will go sleep, you are editing your answer by coping my code dude!

Comment: Ok, I must admit you are doing a good job haha! Keep the good work.